# What type of motor is this? (photo included)

Tags: motor, dc, identification, fan, rotor

I want to make this motor work, but I can't understand what type this is. I supplied 5V DC to the terminals, but it just kept buzzing and the coils were energized. It also had some kind of circuit, but it was not connected to any of the terminals. What do you guys think?

[image: photo of dismantled motor]

Comment: Looks like a permanent magnet motor.

Comment: May be brushless DC

Comment: "some kind of circuit" looks like a Hall effect sensor, which sends timing signals (about the rotor speed) to the motor controller circuit.

Comment: Seconding @Chu, this looks like a permanent-magnet AC motor, also called a brushless DC motor. Only single-phase though.

Answer (score 5):

It's an single phase BLDC (Brush less dc) motor. the circuit is an hall effect sensor to detect the rotor position.

Some thing similar to this
[image]
[follow this link for more information on control and working of an single phase BLDC motor](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00001779A.pdf)